# Rider not showing "Check expression for null" in contextual popup

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

I'm starting with rider and just started doing some of the built-in introductory tutorials.

Just at the beginning (I think it is third step) of the essentials tutorial I am instructed to do this (Can be read on the right) but no option is shown in the contextual popup realted to Checking expression to null.

Must I do anything special for this option to show?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution wasn't loaded correctly. The red exclamation mark in the right upper corner of the editor sais that solution analysis also has errors. In addition, we see lots of red code in the editor. It seems to be the reason for the corresponding action absence. Most likely, it means that you have incorrect MSBuld in Rider settings "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build." Please, check your MSBuild settings. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Toolset_and_Build.html
If it does not help, please submit a support request (https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/.) with attached logs (https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001079770-How-to-collect-Rider-logs-)